# Scripting browser activity - automated clicking

Tags: browser, scripting, macros, imacros

I am dealing with scraping data from web pages. What I do is to "click" some page daily and record the page content, for further extraction. Of course, there are dozens of pages and months to click, so all is automatized. Normally I used `curl` with Cookies and POST, and it worked very well. But I have now some "smart" pages, that use some javascript, sessions, voodoo, whatever, and do not allow to be scraped simply. I really need to click some buttons to get what I want.

So, I want to automatize those actions. What solution (language, plugins, ...) would you recommend? I know [iMacros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMacros); is there any alternative, comparable solution? Or is it the One and Only? (I work under Linux, by the way)

Thanks for all the advice

**Edit**

Related:

- [iMacros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMacros)
- [Watir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watir)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you using Watir with ruby. It's really easy to use, cross-platform and cross-browser. And of course it has a really good documentation.

ruby can be downloaded here: http://www.ruby-lang.org or in your case I would suggest apt-get.

And Watir here: http://watir.com/ but its easyer to install using

```
 gem install watir
```

Don't forget to install and update rubygems.

Comment: I don't think so. There are browser plugins that do that but don't really work because they record the x,y position of the mouse. Then if the page changes its css you have to rerecord your script.

Comment: oops, I deleted my comment after your response. But, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watir#Recorders mentions some recorders